# How to set 'anchor' or 'offset' for 'DomIcon|DomMarker' in Here Map?

Tags: here-api

There is an option named 'anchor' form H.Icon. Is there any counterpart for H.DomIcon?

Or, can I set the offset of H.DomMarker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct counterpart of `anchor` for the `H.DomIcon`. But since a `DomIcon` is used within a `DomMarker` which is created within a DOM element, you can use HTML DOM element styles; `margin` or `padding` to set the offset of the DomIcon/Marker.

Comment: Our requirement is to rotate a DOM(usually div) based on its center, and the center is mapping to the coordination of the marker. For other maps API such as bing maps and google maps, we set 'rotation' property (directly or via css 'transform') of the DOM, then set anchor (or offset) of the DOM(or marker). For here map we can only 'set rotation' (via css 'transform', ) so far, the top-left of the DOM is mapping to the coordinate of the marker. I'm afraid margin or padding can't substitute 'anchor' property.

Comment: See answer from GermanZ in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813574/stick-dom-marker-in-here-maps-on-zooming